# Changing the text on image in python

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library, python-tesseract

Below is my code

I need to find a way to put the changed text (dictionary) and save a new image. Please let me know if any one has a solution.

```py
import pytesseract
from pytesseract import Output
from PIL import Image
import copy

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe'

file = "C:\\Capture.jpg"

img = Image.open(file)
dict_items = pytesseract.image_to_data(img,lang='eng', output_type=Output.DICT)
print("Orignal dictionary :",dict_items)
dict2 = copy.deepcopy(dict_items['text'])
print(dict2)
for itr, txt in enumerate(dict2):
    if txt not in ['',None,'\n','\t','\r',' ']:
        print(txt)
        dict2[itr] = "HAPPY BDAY"
        print(dict2[itr])
print(dict2)
d = {} 
for li in dict2:  
    d.setdefault('text', []).append(li)

print(d)
dict_items.update(d)
print("Updated dictionary :",dict_items)

img.save(fp="img.png")
```

Comment: Can you help me understand?  What are you trying to do?

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to add your input image and the result you want.

Comment: I want to take am image separate the text from the image and replace the old text with my new text. We can take any input image(JPEG or PNG ) is good enough.